# Recommended way to convert IGrouping<TKey, TValue> to IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, grouping

This has got to be a duplicate, but my searching is not yielding the results I want.

It seems this should be fairly straightforward, but no built-in LINQ mechanism seems to be in place to make this happen.  Some help would be appreciated.

...it's also possible I'm doing this wrong.  I have an enumerable set of objects with a property `Foo` that I want to create a dictionary with the `Foo` property the key of a dictionary, where the value is an enumeration of objects having `Foo` as the same value.

Comment: Do you mean `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>`?

Comment: maybe I do.  `IGrouping` is not something I'm very familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
var dict = yourGroup.ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Select(x=>x));
```

Or use `AsEnumerable` for generating values:

```
var dict = yourGroup.ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: Knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks

Comment: This is as close as you'll ever get, but still not quite correct -- the IEqualityComparer may be different.

Comment: @CoryNelson `IEqualityComparer` is not part of **data**, we can always specify the `IEqualityComparer` for the dictionary as whatever we want. I also don't know the way to extract IEqualityComparer from the group, if you know feel free to share it, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: I don't thing it is that big of a deal. 1st we can supply [IEqualityComparer in ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548554(v=vs.110).aspx) and 2nd we supposed to know our data.